# Not able to get some utf-8 characters printed correctly in C++ to txt file

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have some UTF-8 strings in memory (this is part of a bigger system) which are basically name of places in European countries. What I'm trying to do is write them to a text file. I'm on my Linux machine (Fedora). So when I write these name strings (char pointers) to file, the file is getting saved in extended ASCII format.

Now I copy this file to my Windows machine where I need to load these names to mySQL DB. When I open the text file on notepad++, again it defaults the encoding to ANSI. But I can select encoding to UTF-8 and almost all the characters looks as expected except the following 3 characters:- Ő, ő and ű. They are displayed within the text as &#336, &#337 and &#369.

Does anyone has any thought on what might be wrong. I know that these are not part of extended ASCII symbols. But the way I'm writing this to the file is something like:

```
// create out file stream
std::ofstream fs("sample.txt");

// loop through utf-8 formatted string list
if(fs.is_open()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < num_strs; i++) {
        fs << str_name; // unsigned char pointer representing name in utf-8 format
        fs << "\n";
    }
}
fs.close();
```

Everything looks good even with characters like ú and ö and ß. The issue is with the above 3 characters alone. Any thoughts/suggestions/comments on this? Thanks!

As an example, a string like "Gyömrő" shows up as "Gyömr&#369".

Comment: Have you tried using the `write` member function instead of `operator<<` to write the string?

Comment: What are the values your printing? Note, that you'd need to have a C++ 2011 compiler to get a guarantee that Unicode characters can be embedded in the source. Whether writing the files will code convert them is, yet, another issue, though. Personally, I'd suspect you'd want to use `char16_t` or `char32_t` to represent Unicode characters.

Comment: @Prætorian `write` didn't make any difference. @Dietmar I have given an example String in my original post, see last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to identify at which stage the unexpected &#336 HTML entities are introduced. My best guess is, that they are already in the string you are writing to the file.  Use a debugger or add testing code that counts the &s in the string.

That means, your source of information does not strictly use UTF-8 for non-ASCII characters, but occasionally uses [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). This is odd, but possible if your data source is a HTML file (or something like that).

Also, you might want to look at your output file in HEX mode. (There's a nice plugin for Notepad++) This might hopefully help you to understand what UTF-8 really means on the byte level: The 128 ASCII symbols use one byte of a value 0-127. Other symbols use 2-6 bytes (i think), where the first byte must be >127. HTML entities are not really an encoding, more an escape sequence like '\n' '\r'.

Comment: My source was on codepage 1252. Since 1252 do not define characters,  Ő, ő and ű, we were using the html entities to define them. I believe the reason for not using utf-8 format was we wanted to keep the source size as small as possible. Thanks all for the comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If, when opening in Notepad++ and choosing UTF-8, and your characters aren't showing up propery, then they are not encoded as UTF-8.
You also mention "extended ASCII", which has very little to do with unicode encodings.
And my belief is that you are in fact writing your characters as some codepage, for instance "ISO-8859-1".

Try take a look at the byte count of those trouble strings indide your program, and if the byte count is the same as the character count, then you are in fact not encoding it as UTF-8.

Any character that lies outside of the 128 character ASCII table, will be encoded with at least two bytes in UTF-8.

To properly handle unicode within your C++ application, take a look at ICU:
http://site.icu-project.org/

Answer (score -1):

The default `std::codecvt<char, char, mbstate_t>` doesn't do you any good: this is defined to do no conversion at all. You'd need to `imbue()` a `std::locale` with a UTF-8 aware code conversion facet. That said, `char` can't really represent Unicode values. You'd need a bigger type although the values you are looking at actually do fit into a `char` in Unicode but not in any encoding which allows for all values.

The C++ 2011 standard defines a UTF-8 conversion facet `std::codecvt_utf<...>`. However, it isn't specialized for the internal type `char` but only for `wchar_t`, `uint16_t`, and `uint32_t`. Using clang together with libc++, I could get the following to do the right things:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

int main()
{
    std::wofstream out("utf8.txt");
    std::locale utf8(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>());
    out.imbue(utf8);
    out << L"\xd6\xf6\xfc\n";
    out << L"Ööü\n";
}
```

Note that this code use `wchar_t` rather than `char`. It might look reasonable to use `char16_t` or `char32_t` because these are meant to be UCS2 and UCS4 encoded, respectively (if I understand the standard correctly), but there are not stream type defined for them. Setting stream types up for a new character type is somewhat of a pain.

Comment: Sorry, but this is at least partly rubbish. The 8 in UTF-8 stands for the bits used **at least** by a character. UTF-8 is **designed** to be used with default strings. Most string functions are totally agnostic to encoding, and should be (strcpy for example). What you put in your wide strings is **not** UTF-8, \xd6 is the hex-representation of a Win-1252 encoded Ö. It still uses one byte, but is stored in a two or 4 byte space (depending on the wchar_t definition. The UTF-8 representation of Ö is \x96\xc3 in HEX, using two bytes.

Comment: kriver just wants to output a string "as is". To achieve this, no conversion or imbuing has to take place. His problem is somewhere else in the chain.

Comment: UTF-8 is, indeed, designed to extend ASCII, i.e., characters encoded with values `0` to `127` use one byte with an identical value when encoded using UTF-8. The characters in question don't match this description and will use multiple byte when being UTF-8 encode. It happens that they do. The `L'\xd6'` create a `wchar_t` for the Unicode code point for O-umlaut which gets translated when writing by means of the code conversion facet into the byte sequence `\x96c3`. I think that my program indeed creates the correct sequence of UTF-8 encoded characters.

Comment: It is hard to say what kriver wants. What he tries certainly does not work because the internally use representation for `char` almost certainly isn't UTF-8. If it were, then his program would do the right thing because the default conversion done by `std::codecvt<char, char, mbstate_t>` is the identify. It is, of course, quite possible that his original file indeed contained what he wanted and that it got converted at a later time. The way to verify this would be to run `od -xc sample.txt`: this should show the appropriate UTF-8 byte sequence.